# Replacing a table view present in view with another table view in another screen

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I want to change my current table view with another table view, that is present in another view.

It sounds wierd but i still want to do it, can please some one help.

Scenarios is this..

1. I have a view in that i created a table view with custom cells.
2. Now I want this table view to be present on another view.
3. On that view, there aleady exist a table view.

I dont want to delete it just want to change it.
So on click of button 1, the same view with replace table view comes
and on button 2.. Same view with old table view come.

Hope you all get me now.

Comment: First please turn off your caps lock.

Comment: You could all pile on with downvotes, or someone could just edit it.

Comment: If czechboy's answer isn't enough, you should be more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove an UIView from its superview without deleting it by `removeFromSuperview`. Then you can again `addSubview` to the other place. But I don't understand your complete use case to help more.

Comment: The answer is right but not good enough, you should be SHOUTING IT JUST LIKE THE OP DID IN THE QUESTION! ANYWAY +1!

Comment: guys i m a newbiee... n my senior dnt want same view to be created all the time, just for a change in their table view.. i can copy as many views i want .. n paste diff table views on dem.. but he caught me.. n nw i m struck..:P

Comment: Well even if you are a newbie...do you see anyone else question, or anything else for that matter, in ALL CAPS?!

Comment: @Renan.. i knw i shudn't have used.. caps.. i m sorry for dat.. but it surely.. shows my emotions of being desperate for ans.. :P

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.. Maybe you should use navigation controller logic? And push and pop second controller with second table?